# Why are SPAM questions kept?

Tags: discussion, spam

I am aware that deleted questions are stored by [StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.com/deleted). Recently while having  a look at my flagging history on mouse hover I was able to view a SPAM question's content.

For example:

> [image]

While inspecting closer through Chrome:

> [image]

Does the community save SPAM question information too? Any reason behind storing spammy question summaries?

Comment: Nothing is deleted.  Not even what's deleted by [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We usually soft delete posts - not hard delete them.

This includes deleted spam posts.

Doing anything else would complicate the infrastructure and code, which we want to avoid.

As deleted content is only visible to +10k users, the majority of users will never bump into them anyway.

So - why remove them?

You can always flag such posts for moderator attention, so the content can be edited out (yes, it will still be in revisions, but, that's an extra click and again, only for +10k users).

Comment: I assume annother major reason for keeping everything is accountability

Comment: @RichardTingle - That is that aspect, yes.

Comment: And unless I am mistaken, only answers are openly visible to 10K users.  Questions are not unless you have the link, so you are never going to see deleted SPAM posts unless you want too.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Pretty much. You would have to go to the spam question directly

Comment: I also find keeping around the content of spam to be useful in determining if spammers have posted this same content before. If it's a trend, we can look at applying a blacklist to the terms involved or see if there were additional spam accounts that we missed when cleaning up new posts.